# How can I create a Twilio video connection in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I'm working through a Twilio tutorial on how to add video to my node.js app, and I'm stuck on connecting to a room shown in this step: https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/javascript-v1-getting-started#connect-to-a-room

The code snippet in question is:

```
const { connect } = require('twilio-video');

connect('$TOKEN', { name:'my-new-room' }).then(room => {
  console.log(`Successfully joined a Room: ${room}`);
  room.on('participantConnected', participant => {
    console.log(`A remote Participant connected: ${participant}`);
  });
}, error => {
  console.error(`Unable to connect to Room: ${error.message}`);
});
```

When I add that code to my app.js file, in terminal I get the following error:

`Unable to connect to Room: getUserMedia is not supported`

However, I verified that my browser supports getUserMedia so I believe this error is faulty and not displaying the true error (I've triple verified my browser is supported, and even reinstalled chrome). I'm also using a secure HTTPS connection through ngrok.

The error is server side to begin with. Perhaps I'm not implemented the code in the right place?

My app.js files looks like this:

```
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const { connect } = require('twilio-video');



app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + 'public/css'))
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + 'public/js'))

app.set('views', './views')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('student')
})

const { connect } = require('twilio-video');

connect('$TOKEN', { name:'my-new-room' }).then(room => {
  console.log(`Successfully joined a Room: ${room}`);
  room.on('participantConnected', participant => {
    console.log(`A remote Participant connected: ${participant}`);
  });
}, error => {
  console.error(`Unable to connect to Room: ${error.message}`);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.info("Listening on " + port))
```

I don't know where to put this connection code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You code to connect to Twilio Video should be in the front-end.

That is the code that takes the user's camera and microphone (which is why it is complaining about no `getUserMedia`, a browser API) and connects to a Twilio Video room. This should be running in your client-side, sorry that the documentation doesn't make that obvious.

Can I point out that you are following the v1 documentation there, I'd recommending following [the v2 documentation here instead](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/javascript-v2-getting-started).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! In regards to where I need to place it in my frontend: I'm using Node.js and EJS to display my html. Would I include the "connect('$TOKEN').." code snippet inside a JS file that is referenced into an EJS view as a script tag? Or would I need to use a more sophisticated framework like React to make this work?

Comment: In general for Twilio Video you can use plain JS in a script tag or a framework. Twilio Video doesn't mind what you are using to build your page. For the example code in the documentation you are going through, you should just use plain JS though.

Comment: Do you know of a  basic file structure format for what I would need to incorporate the video tutorial? I'm a bit lost on how to exactly connect everything. Currently, inside my project folder i have an app.js shown above with my main route, a views folder containing my html content for my route, and a public folder container a js files to be called into a my html files through a script tag. 

Is this setup adequate, and if so, where would you recommend placing the connect to video room code? (sorry this is long, If there's any recommended resources u have i'd be happy to check it out)

Comment: If you are using a setup like that I would recommend you include [the Twilio Video script onto your HTML page using the CDN](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/javascript#cdn) (otherwise you'd need a build step and there's no need to complicate things). Other than that, your setup sounds fine for trying this out by following the documentation.

Comment: Ok great, thank you. I'm able to have my video and audio accessed by my app! I didn't see a way to be able to actually show the video on the browser in the tutorial. Would you be able to point me in the right direction? I appreciate your patience

Comment: Huh, that is weird! There is a section on [displaying a remote participant's media](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/javascript-v2-getting-started#display-a-remote-participants-video) which you can actually apply to `room.localParticipant` as well. I also have [a repo on GitHub with a getting started video application that is fully commented](https://github.com/philnash/first-twilio-video-application/blob/master/assets/video.js) that might help too. Check out [the README for how to run this project here](https://github.com/philnash/first-twilio-video-application).

Comment: Thanks Phil. I appreciate your patience with me. I've looked at this quite a bit today so I definitely glossed over that documentation, I need some sleep! Your responses have been really helpful. Thank you!